# Connect to Database in Url

Tags: android, database

guys i have a Database in the Url eg:www.myurl.com/mydb .

I need to connect to this db(mydb) how to connect to this?

```
URL url = new URL("http://myurl.com/mydb");
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
            ucon.connect();
```

I think the above is used to connect to the url

please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String httpResponse = null;
    BufferedReader rd = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    String line = null;

    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://myurl.com/mydb");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        sb = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + '\n');
        }

        // Response is stored here.
        httpResponse = sb.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
```

Comment: thanks i am using sqllite database and that database is in my website http://myurl.com/ how to connnect and manipulate on that please help

Comment: This is it. Goofy you just have to do this and play with the data you'll have on httpResponse. You can parse it, convert it to JSON Object.... Here's my +1 triad

Answer (score 0):

You clearly require `Web-Services` to manipulate the Data on the Database.